# All the filters are generated by a chain of elements?

Tags: lattice-orders

If we consider a chain of elements in a lattice, then this chain is able to generate a filter. My question is whether every filter is generated by a suitable chain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathbf L$ be the lattice with underlying set
$$\{\varnothing\} \cup \{X\subseteq \mathbb R: |\mathbb R\setminus X| \in \mathbb N\},$$
ordered by inclusion. 
So $\mathbf L$ is the set of cofinite subsets of $\mathbb R$ together with the empty set. 
It is easy to see this forms a lattice.
Now let $F=\{X\subseteq \mathbb R: |\mathbb R\setminus X| \in \mathbb N\}$ (the cofinite subsets of $\mathbb R$), and let $C$ be a chain such that $C \subseteq F$.
For each element $c$ of $C$ , 
$$c= \mathbb R \setminus A,$$
where $A$ is a finite set.
Thus
$$C=\{ \mathbb R \setminus A_i : i \in I \},$$
where $A_i$ is a finite set.
Since $C$ is a chain, so is $(A_i)_{i \in I}$ (because $\mathbb R \setminus A_i \subseteq \mathbb R\setminus A_j$ implies that $A_j \subseteq A_i$), and indeed, it is a well-ordered set. 
It follows that $\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i$ is countable, whence
$$\bigcap C = \bigcap\{ \mathbb R \setminus A_i : i \in I \} = \mathbb R \setminus \bigcup_{i\in I}A_i \neq \varnothing.$$
Let $x_0 \in \bigcap C$.
Then $x_o \in c$ for all $c \in C$.

For each $x \in \mathbb R$, let $A_x = \mathbb R\setminus\{x\}$.
Clearly, $A_x \in F$, for every $x \in \mathbb R$.
In particular, $A_{x_0} \in F$.
If $c\in C$ is such that $c \subseteq A_{x_0}$, then $x_0 \notin c$, which cannot happen as we saw.
So there exists no $c \in C$ such that $c \subseteq A_{x_0}$, and therefore $A_{x_0}$ doesn't belong to the filter generated by $C$.

Comment: The example is perfect! Moreover, the proof becomes evident if we refer to the dual notion of ideal. Indeed, let $I$ be the class of finite subsets of the set $\mathbb R$ of real numbers and put $L$ be equal with $L \cup \{\mathbb R\}$. Then $I$ is an ideal of $L$. Let $C$ be a chain contained in $I$ and $U$ its union.Then, since $U$ is enumerable, a real number $r$ exists which is not in $U$.  $\{r\}$ is an element of $I$ which is not in the ideal generated by the chain. Thus, no chain is able to generate $I$.

Comment: Obviously, it is also necessary to prove that $U$ is countable

Comment: @G.Gerla Yes, you are right in your comment. It is obviously equivalent, but none of the examples would be easier to prove. So it is preferable to give a direct answer to the question. But I agree that the order dual should be accepted as an answer as well. By the way, you may just as well accept and/or upvote the answer. See [Why is voting important?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) and [What is reputation? How do I earn (and loose) it?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: My query is related with point-free geometry. Indeed, there are two possible definitions of a point in point-free geometry. Whitehead's definition is based on the notion of "abstraciton process", i.e. a totally ordered class of regions. In lattice theory the "points" are defined by the filters. I am interested to the defference between these two approaches. A better example for me should be geometrical in nature. In a metric space the filter of the neighobord of a point is generated by the set of concentric balls. Is there a topological space in which this filter is not generated by a chain?

Comment: @G.Gerla I don't know. That is also a whole different question, which you can ask, preferably with the tags 'lattice-orders', 'general-topology' and/or 'metric-spaces'. Notice that the concept of ball doesn't make sense in a general topological space. Anyway, although the lattice $L$ above is the lattice of open sets of a topological space on $\mathbb R$, I don't think it provides one such example, because the filter $F$ that is not generated by a chain is not a neighbourhood of any element, since for every $x$, the open set $A_x$ is in $F$, but $x \notin A_x$.

Comment: An idea is to repeat your cofinites-based example by substituting   the Euclidean plane instead of R. In fact the class of co-finite subsets of the plane toghether with the whole plane is a filter of open subsets in the lattice of the open sets. This filter cannot be generated by a chain (I have to control). If this is correct, your first answer suggests/is the correct answer. It is also possible to consider the question in the Boolean algebra of all subsets of the plane. In this case we have to consider the filter generated by the cofinites.